# Should behavior of Cube[] and Cuboid[] be the same in these cases?

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, export, regions

**Bug introduced in v12.0 (?) and fixed as of 12.3.1**

While attempting to export a symbol with head Region (or Graphics3D) as an OBJ file, I run in to problems using `Cube[]` that are not readily apparent with `Cuboid[]`.

```
c1 = Region[Cube[]];
c2 = Region[Cube[100]];
c3 = Region[Cuboid[]];
c4 = Region[Cuboid[{100, 100, 100}]];
Export["c1.obj", c1];
Export["c2.obj", c2];
Export["c3.obj", c3];
Export["c4.obj", c4];
Export["c1a.obj", 
  TransformedRegion[c1, ScalingTransform[100 {1, 1, 1}]]];
Export["c3a.obj", 
  TransformedRegion[c3, ScalingTransform[100 {1, 1, 1}]]];
```

In this example, file c1a.obj doe not get generated with two errors being thrown: *Region cannot be exported to the OBJ format* and *RuleDelayed cannot be exported to the OBJ format*.  The same behavior is observed if Graphics3D symbols are used.

**Is this behavior working as intended?**  I believe this to be a bug - I am using Version 12.0.0 at the moment.

Comment: Internally from tracing I've found `Cube[]` is really a `Polyhedron` or gets converted to one, while `Cuboid[]` is a `Parallelepiped`. It seems any of the `Polyhedron` objects also fail to export, but only if they've undergone some sort of transformation to the region. Consider this failing case too: `Export["dodeca.obj", 
 TransformedRegion[Region[Dodecahedron[]], 
  RotationTransform[\[Pi]/4, {0, 0, 1}]]]` - I'm using Windows v12.1.1

Comment: If you replace `Region[Cube[]]` with `MeshRegion[Cube[]]` you should have no trouble transforming and exporting it and it works for me in v12.1.1. You could also use `MeshRegion` only when you export, if you don't want the mesh elsewhere.

Comment: @flinty so it does look like a bug of some sort, although there are a number of workarounds like you suggest.

Comment: Yes, you should report it. Even if the `Region[Cube[]]` is somehow wrong , it certainly shouldn't fail in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug found in v12.0 and fixed as of 12.3.1.